# Request PUT to parse.com on REST API from Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, parse-platform

I'm trying to do an update on an object from my db (parse.com), So, I saw the docs and look likes so easy but I think I forget some dummy thing... but I'm not able to find it... Could you help me, please?

I'm doing this request:

```
$.http({
     method: 'PUT',
     url: myURL + 'objectID of object to update',
     headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id': appId, 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': restId,
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
     data: {'name' : 'new name'}

  }).success(function(data){
     console.log(data)

  }).error(function(data){
     console.log(data)

  });
```

here, the docs says like you have to do this kind of request:
https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#objects-updating-objects

Thanks a lot, if you need some information more, let me know.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I'm getting an error 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Does myURL have a trailing '/'?  If not, that would explain a 400.

Comment: @danh Yes, the url is correct because I'm using this url for GET request. I erase data and change the method to GET and works fine...

Comment: Oh.  Good hint.  Does a non-user have sufficient permission to write the class?

Comment: ?? I don't understand your last question, I'm calling trough API REST and call with angular service (like AJAX), So, I think everybody can change data with keys. @danh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Server of parse.com, must get a json object, for this reason I wrote content type json-application but I forgot write this:

```
var obj = {'name': 'new name'};

. . .

//inside of http service
data: JSON.stringify(object);
```

I will never forget that!